# cannot add members to tabular model roles using visual studio 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I've created a tabular model project in Visual Studio 2012 and everything seems to work properly until I go to use the Role Manager.  I can create roles easily enough, but when I click the Add button on the members tab for a role - absolutely nothing happens.  No dialog, no error, nothing.

I'm pretty disgusted by this, but I thought I would ask if anyone else has seen this behavior or knows a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a workaround for this.  On two separate computers, installing the following SQL Server features resolved the issue:

- "Client Tools Connectivity"
- "Management Tools - Basic"
- "Management Tools - Complete"